# How to fix always float timepicker even scroll?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently using this [time-picker package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rc-time-picker). I checked out on their sandbox, the timepicker just works fine no problem at scrolling.

**EDITED:** I found the cause it because it was wrapped by a div with `flex`. But I can't remove the `flex` because it is needed for sidebar.

Someone knows how to make the timepicker not floated when scrolling inside a div `flex`?
[image]

---

Here is my codes:

```
<div className="flex-1 w-full bg-adminGray-100 pb-px-100 overflow-scroll overflow-x-hidden">        
  <TimePicker
    showSecond={true}
    format="HH:mm"
    showSecond={false}
    inputReadOnly
    allowEmpty={false}
    disabled={false}
  />
  <p>long text here</p>
</div>
```

Comment: The documentation has as placement option. My guess is there is something internal to the library that might control the placement.

try using one of these options -> ['topLeft', 'topRight', 'bottomLeft', 'bottomRight'] I think it will change the placement but it will likely still float.

Comment: @FujiRoyale its still not working using `placement`. however I found out the cause. Its because it was wrap by div with `flex`. But i can't remove `flex` because it is needed for my  sidebar.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why but it fixed it by wrapping the codes with `absolute` position.

```
<div style="position:absolute">
    <div className="flex">
        //more codes here
        <div className="flex-1 w-full bg-adminGray-100 pb-px-100 overflow-scroll overflow-x-hidden">        
          <TimePicker
            showSecond={true}
            format="HH:mm"
            showSecond={false}
            inputReadOnly
            allowEmpty={false}
            disabled={false}
          />
          <p>long text here</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```